# Uniswap Price Feed.- Get price of a Token in a Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

I am looking to retrieve the current price of a token from Uniswap. I have successfully used the ChainLink oracle api to get the price of BTC/USD, but I want to now integrate Uniswap price feeds.

I cannot seem to find one that just retrieves the current price of a token in ETH. Has anybody ever attempted this before?

Answer (score 2):

Uniswap has an [SDK](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/quick-start/) through which you can fetch the gas price. See [their example](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/pricing/) in their documentation :

```js
    import { ChainId, Token, WETH, Fetcher, Route } from '@uniswap/sdk'
    
    const DAI = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F', 18)
    
    // note that you may want/need to handle this async code differently,
    // for example if top-level await is not an option
    const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(DAI, WETH[DAI.chainId])
    
    const route = new Route([pair], WETH[DAI.chainId])
    
    console.log(route.midPrice.toSignificant(6)) // 201.306
    console.log(route.midPrice.invert().toSignificant(6)) // 0.00496756
```

Comment: It's javascript, not solidity